# Where to find the game "Brauner-Sollig Hildesheim 2001"

Tags: famous-games, blunder, identify-this

In a lesson from learningchess.net they presented this game. The blunder is so big that I wanted to check more about this game, but I cannot find anything online.

> Brauner-Sollig  Hildesheim 2001

[image]

Comment: Try searching the FEN

Comment: in mega database 2019 i found 57 games which arrived this position including the one you have mentioned here. first recorded game shows year 1994. in fact this is not even the first game where black resigned after Nc6

Comment: No entry in Lichess (finally *any* n00b knows the trap), neither is the poor guy playing Black known in the German rating database. And be sure, n00bs fell into the trap right after Petroff invented his defense (around 1800-1850 I guess).

Comment: @HaukeReddmann Are you sure?  ([1](https://lichess.org/qaVEWBci#9), [2](https://lichess.org/MVhThJyy#9), [3](https://lichess.org/WAnvKhfn#9), [4](https://lichess.org/9sOspdPm#9) and many more)

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: I entered the line and got no result from the LiChess analysis engine. I think my results were limited to tournament games (and possibly a minimum ELO) - your findings are fast games throughout.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann My mistake. What about [G25](https://lichess.org/vuUMoclh/black#9) or [G30](https://lichess.org/dNz03eet/black#9)?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: I have the nagging feeling the analysis engine only considers OTB play, not online.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann fair point.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call that a famous game. It's actually a trappy line of the Petroff defense.

```
[Event "?"]
[Site "?"]
[Date "?"]
[Round "?"]
[White "?"]
[Black "?"]
[Result "?"]
[FEN ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Nxe5 Nxe4 4. Qe2 Nf6?? {Qe7 is correct here} 5. Nc6+ {Regardless of how they block the check, black loses their queen for the knight}
```